# Manual ARIMA forecasting in python

Tags: python, arima, forecast

I'm trying to make manual ARIMA prediction
using the following parameters:

fitted parameters using ARIMA python
[image: fitted parameters using ARIMA python]

How can I write the manual prediction formula using the above parameters?

I'm trying to make manual prediction to compare it with the prediction result of python forecast function.

Comment: Are you using the `statsmodels` library? It should have a [`predict`](https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.12.0/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.predict.html)-method available.

Comment: Please don't post any textual information as an image: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors